# Redux store configuration issue

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am developing an application using react-redux and evaluate  the performance of the application. My redux store configuration works and i don't have any issues until i add react performance to applayapplyMiddleware. The redux store  configuration:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './../reducers/rootReducer';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { loadeState, saveState } from './localstorage';
import ReactPerformance from 'react-performance'

const history = createHistory();
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
const persitantState = loadeState();
const performance = ReactPerformance.createNotifier(); 

export default function configureStore() {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    // persitantState,
    composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, middleware, loggerMiddleware, performance)
    )
  );

  store.subscribe(() => {
    //saveState();
  });
  return store;
}
```

the error: 
[image]

I follow the instruction from this git repository, 
[react-performance](https://github.com/amsul/react-performance#use-with-redux)

I need the statistical data and graphs for my report. I couldn't figure out why i got the error. I need some tips, i am just hold hostage by this error.

Comment: In your code, you are not adding the performance enhancer after your middleware (or at all). Can you update your example?

Comment: I update the performance and included into applyMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

Your store setup is wrong, but that's because the docs at https://github.com/amsul/react-performance are also wrong.

`ReactPerformance.createNotifier()` doesn't return a Redux *middleware*, it returns a Redux *store enhancer*.  It needs to be composed together with the `applyMiddleware()` store enhancer, not passed to `applyMiddleware()`.  The code snippet in the repo README is correct, but the description as a middleware is wrong.

So, a correct example:

```
composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, middleware, loggerMiddleware),
    performance
);
```

I filed an issue to have that README updated.